# Минимальное значение, возвращаемое функцией

Tags: python, алгоритм, поиск, r

Например есть функция:

```
def f(x)
```

которая возвращает мне число. х - аргумент из диапазона от 0.0001 до 0.9999.
Нужно найти такое х, при котором значение функции будет минимальным. И есть аналогичная ситуация, для двух аргументов:

```
def f(x, y)
```

найти такие х и у, при которых функция вернёт минимальное значение.

Какие есть методы, кроме простого перебора, чтобы это было быстро на Python, а лучше R?
[image: Вот такая функция на языке R]
Мне нужно подобрать минимальные альфу и бету

Comment: Без знания, что за функция - никаких.

Comment: А какая функция? Если произвольная то только перебор. На Python можно сделать через itertools.

Comment: Вообще это функцияExponential тип прогнозирования, и там минимальное значение зависит от параметра alpha и beta

Comment: Если функция непрерывная или около того, посмотрите в сторону: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/optimize

Answer (score 2):

> это функция Exponential

Если исследуемая функция **непрерывна** на некотором участке (экспонента - непрерывная функция), то к ней применимо множество методов поиска экстремумов функций. Например:

1. Аналитически. Простейший вариант - берём производную и приравниваем её нулю. Там где это ур-ние имеет решение  - экстремум.
2. Численно. Простейший вариант - метод деления интервала пополам. http://kafedra-des.narod.ru/download/chisl_metod_poiska_ekstremuma.pdf

Comment: Не могу молчать! :) 1. Экстремум (т.е. минимальное или максимальное значение) не обязательно там, где производная равна нулю - нужно еще проверять границы замкнутого интервала (кстати, при открытом с обеих сторон интервале в строгом математическом смысле функция может не иметь экстремумов). Да хотя бы возьмите `f(x)==x` - где у нее производная равна нулю?... :) Кстати, метод 2 (деления пополам) тоже может не всегда работать...

Comment: Ну вот методичка очень сильно пригодилась, так как реализовал метод "Золотое сечение" , но как я понял он только линейный. Вроде на его основе можно запилить метод покоординатного спуска, но как это все слепить нормально не пойму

Comment: @Harry - "может не всегда работать"
- Никто Вам не запрещает рассказать формучанам о методе, который работает **всегда** :-)

Comment: @Sergey Крайне рекомендую порыться в старых "Квантах", там была замечательная статья о поиске экстремумов, и ненавязчиво было показано, что такого метода нет. Кроме разве что исчерпывающего перебора с заданной точностью (ну, вот и рассказал... :))

Comment: @Harry - "было показано, что такого метода нет"
- Зачем же Вы тогда требуете от меня, что бы я его показал ?!  :-)

Comment: Да где я такое требую? процитируйте, pls...